# Email Notification Architecture Questions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, architecture, smtp

We are looking to develop an email notification service where emails can be scheduled daily, weekly, or hourly based on certain actions that happen within our system (User Registration) or summary emails sent every Friday for example.

What is the best way to handle making sure duplicate emails are not sent? We thought about maybe having the application write a record to a queue whenver a system action happens but this would seem to have one more point of failure. Or maybe just making all notifications data driven, for example, select all users where created on date is greater than now. But with this scenario we need a way to make sure if the service runs again duplicate emails are not sent..

any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My 2 cents

1) **Queues.** Queues are great for the tasks where you want to have a 'single entry and single exit' type of architecture. Queues decouple the systems and allow you to load balance the system. They are usually used with the *multiple workers* on one and another end. You will just add (maybe a lot) of messages to the queue, and later run a *bulk* dequeue. IMO that is irrational memory and resource consumption.

2) **Data-driven via Users**. Much easier to implement, however for each notification you will check *every* user and will put heavy load on db.

3) **Data-driven via UserNotifications**. Alternatively, you can create a separate table UserNotifications, where each user will be added once he has registered. It is much easier to select the needed users within given time frame and you don't store them in memory. Once notification sent, you remove the user from UserNotifications table.

Comment: Great ideas! What about emails that are generated not based on user actions...weekly summary emails? U create a separate table for each to make sure dups are not sent?

Comment: @Marco do you need to have many notifications types at the same time? Are there many admin users with different notification policies? If you have only one admin and there is only one possible notification at a time, you can just delete the users from the NotificationUsers table (of coz you keep them in the Users table).

Comment: There are about 20 different types. No admin is involved...it's all automated

Comment: @Marco, so you have ~20 notification types, scheduled at different time intervals, and working at the same time? Once 1 user registration has been collected by one notification, it should not reappear in any other notification, is this correct?

Comment: Correct. Just notified once per notification

Comment: @Marco, So can you just delete the user from the UserNotification table? Or mark it as notified by *[insert correct name]* notification?